# Android Fragment stack empty after rotate

Tags: android

I'm using a `FragmentActivity` to display a stack of `Fragments` in a single activity app. This is working fine and I can move through the fragments and hit back to go back up the stack until I rotate the device when I end up with the `Fragment` on the top of the stack rotated but hitting the back button takes me back to the root `Fragment` with all other `Fragment`s in between gone.

I'm using the following code to add a `Fragment` to the stack:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.mainContentViewContainer, newFragment, "DetailFragment");
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

What could be causing the stack to be empty after rotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing android to not restart the Activity, adding `android:configChanges` into `AndroidManifest.xml`, is wrong.

Keeping this in mind:

> What could be causing the stack to be empty after rotate?

Due of the Android behaviour, when you rotate the screen the MainActivity will be restarted. You can override this behaviour with the `android:configChanges` option of the AndroidManifest file.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been looking at that but the documentation seems to suggest that the stack will be maintained by the system on rotate. It maintains the first and last Fragments but nothing in between. What should I be doing in onConfigurationChanged() to maintain the stack?

Comment: nothing. If you add android:configChanges="orientation" android will keep the state for you. Give it a try

Comment: if you are targetin android 3.0 add this one android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: That worked! I've been scratching my head over this for hours and it was that simple! I will accept this as the answer as soon as SO allows.

Comment: This is not the solution. This is a hack and should be avoided!

Comment: @frostymarvelous I know, but I am not able to delete it because the answer was accepted. I edited it encouraging users not to do that. Thanks for your input